# Actions on Google - Receiving 200, but no notification

Tags: push-notification, actions-on-google

I am using a webhook and c# to fulfill my logic within an Action.

I have subscribed to two intents, and have captured the "UpdateUserId".

Here is the notification payload

```
        { 
            "customPushMessage": {
                "target": {
                    "userId": "ABwppHFW6M9ASVqbKFBigM8N0mgssCJmPlwarmgzil_Nk_YsdZ1evzTAggEh0aEsctjOIYg2uHc8n7KfzNuHLuJoirXW",
                    "intent": "NotificationIntent",
                    "argument": {
                        "rawText": "Notification Argument Raw Text",
                        "textValue": "Notification Argument Text Value",
                        "name": "Notification Argument"
                    },
                    "locale": "en-US"
                },
                "userNotification": {
                    "title": "Notification Title",
                    "text": "Notification Text"
                }
            }
        }
```

I am sending my notification using the following code blocks

```
    private static async Task<string> GetAccessTokenFromJsonKeyAsync(string jsonKeyFilePath, params string[] scopes)
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(jsonKeyFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            return await GoogleCredential
                .FromStream(stream) // Loads key file  
                .CreateScoped(scopes) // Gathers scopes requested  
                .UnderlyingCredential // Gets the credentials  
                .GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync(); // Gets the Access Token  
        }
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendNotificationMessage(ProactiveMessage proactiveMessage)
    {
        try
        {
            var accessToken = await GetAccessTokenFromJsonKeyAsync("key.json", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/actions.fulfillment.conversation");

            var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(proactiveMessage);
            var payload = "{\"customPushMessage\": " + serialized + "}";

            // Wrap our JSON inside a StringContent which then can be used by the HttpClient class
            var httpContent = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

            var httpResponseMessage = await _httpClient.PostAsync($"{_hostUrl}", httpContent);

            Console.WriteLine(httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode ? "Successfully sent notification message." : $"Failed to send notification message with {httpResponseMessage.StatusCode}.");

            return httpResponseMessage;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Google Assistant Service: Failed to send notification message with exception: {ex.Message}");
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
```

The method returns a 200 Response.  However, a notification never shows up on my phone.

I am not sure what my next steps for debugging are.

Since notifications are stil not public, is this a common issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I received 200 status code but no notifications arrived at the target device.

I tried it again in approximately 2 days and it worked with no problems and have been working ever since.
The only explanation I could come up with is that there is some configuration running in the background.